# Is there anything similar to Central Limit Theorem for Variance for Hypothesis Testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, central-limit-theorem

[Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) says, "given certain conditions, the arithmetic mean of a sufficiently large number of iterates of independent random variables, each with a well-defined expected value and well-defined variance, will be approximately normally distributed".

So this can be used in Hypothesis Testing, that even a distribution $M(\mu, \sigma)$ is not a normal distribution, if $x \sim M(\mu, \sigma)$, the mean of $n$ samples, $\bar x$, shall follow normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma / \sqrt{n})$. The parameter $\mu$ has a way of hypothesis testing.

However, how about the Variance?

For normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma)$, the $\sigma$ of $n$ samples follows $\chi^2(n)$ distribution, based on this one can set up the hypothesis testing.

If the distribution $M(\mu, \sigma)$ is not normal, is there any similar way to set up a hypothesis testing for the Var (or standard deviation)?

What I can think of now is find the 5% and 95% percentile from the distribution, and change this to a binomial test. But this sounds a bit loose?

Comment: "*the $σ$ of $n$ samples follows $χ^2(n)$ distribution*" --- you mean something else there; like $(n-1)s^2/\sigma^2$ follows a $\chi^2_{n-1}$. Obviously the CLT often applies to sample variances, since (aside a minor handwave about $n$ vs $n-1$) it's an average. Under some circumstances (at least anecdotally) a sum of squares can behave like a scaled chi-square but I'm not sure of where to point you for that, nor how to work out what the scaling factor might be, nor exactly the circumstances in which it can be expected to work.

Comment: yes i mean the $(n-1)s^2/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ , am looking for something like this...

Comment: Invoking the CLT to justify Normal-theory tests based on a sample mean is already suspect: one first must check that the sample size is sufficiently large for the *asymptotic* Normal behavior to have been approached. The CLT works for variances, too--after all, they are closely related to averages (of *squared* values)--but it usually takes a *much* larger sample size before the sampling distribution becomes close enough to Normal for that to be a good approximation. Thus variance tests require more care to apply; they are sensitive to assumptions; and there is no universal test.